# Do we want this kind of content?

Tags: discussion

I have seen a few questions like [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18188/top-10-web-application-security-checks) recently: two or three individuals agree an article that's been published somewhere, one of them asks a question, and then the others copy/paste the answer from the article.  [Here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-guerilla-testing) is another one.

Does this behavior line up with the content we want to have here?

Comment: The second one is one of my favorite newer questions. I was not aware that the top answer was from an article.

The first, to me, is an extremely opinionated question that could have likely been answered by google.

Comment: My gut says no. Definitely to the first one, but that's more a question of the question itself as opposed to the genre. The second one seems fine as a question were it be grass roots. If it's a manufactured question, I'm inclined to think no, but that's just saying no to manufactured questions, not to raising questions relating to a recent article. I'd need some time to draft a truly good answer on it.

Comment: I have no objections to reasonable questions, but I've been flagging the copy/pasted answers as inappropriate because they present the text of the article as the user's own words.

Comment: I don't want to discourage anyone from contributing, but these individuals may need a word from the moderator to encourage the kind of behavior we want.

Comment: While trying to respect the privacy of the users involved, I did engage in some outreach that seems to have been effective. You're absolutely right, we don't want to shut down passionate contributors - we just need to channel that energy into helpful material instead of harmful material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions are not good questions for a sites like the ones on Stack Exchange.  The reason that these are not good questions is because they are simple questions looking for basic information that can be found by doing a simple search of The Internet.

> What is X?

**Answer:** Search for "what is X?" on the internet

**Answer:** Search Wikipedia for X

For most things Wikipedia is close to the truth.

I don't think that this site is meant to be another repository of basic information, but rather a place to come for answers to questions like

> How would I implement Guerilla Testing for my product X, given y restriction?

or

> How do I test for a specific security vulnerability with X testing framework?